# Sub sampling a dataset without losing the distribution

Tags: clustering, sampling

Suppose that I have a huge data set with high number of dimensions (components).
For computational purposes I would like to take just a sample of this data set and work with it instead of working with the huge data set itself.
Is there a good way or technique to sample a dataset?

I was thinking to choose a sample randomly but in this way it is possible that the distribution of the sample will not be the same as the distribution of the original data set.

Example: If I have 2000000 data on that data set and within these data 80% of those data will be from one group(cluster) and the others will be in the other clusters (not related to the 80% of above mentioned data). Now, if I randomly select a sample most probably I will have all almost the data taken from the 80% and not from the other 20% of the data.
So I am looking for a good way to take a sample from such a data set and I dont want the small clusters to be lost. Because as I said those 80% of original data belong to one closter and the remaining 20% belong to some other small clusters. As a result, I think that if I randomly take a sample from these data and then I apply a clustering algorithm on this sample, most probably I will be loosing small clusters

Comment: Do you know which data point belongs to which cluster before you do the sampling?  If not, do you have variables which you think are related to the clusters before you do the sampling?

Comment: The problem is that I dont have a prior knowledge about the original data set. I want to cluster it and I was thinking to do it on this way, by down-sampling it and in this way the algorithm will take less time to cluster the data(or at least I can give the sample as an initialization of the algorithm - K-Means)

Comment: Actually if you sample *at random*, you should have next to 80% from the larger group, and 20% from the remainder... how come you think this will differ substantially? This sounds more as if you want to oversample the smaller classes, but that would bias your data the other way.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I think that this will affect my clusters at the end. I think that small clusters will be lost when I take a sample from the data set.

Comment: Only if they are too tiny and you downsample too much. By their relative share, they will remain as visible as they were before. If you try to "oversample" them, you distort your data.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse do you have any written form about what you said? Any paper or book or something to prove this fact?

Comment: This is statistics 101, and pretty much the definition of independence. It's only when you have a dependency between your random sample and your data when you lose relative shares substantially.

Comment: On a mathematical level, look at the **Binomial distribution**. When you have 20% of being from cluster B, the *mean* number of $n$ samples being from cluster B is $0.20 * n$. You can even give variance, and thus error bounds.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thank You for your answer. I dont have that book and I couldnt find anything related to my question(on some slides given from that book). Anyway I will try to finb that book and make sure about your claiming. About Binomial distribution I didnt understant what you wanted to say and how does this distribution helps me. I dont know the distribution of the data in advance

Comment: That wasn't a book reference. Statistics 101 is the common american course reference for any "introduction to statistics" class. This is very basic material, sampling.
Binomial distributions *is* just what occurs when you random sample from data with a fixed probability of having classes A or B. This does *not* make assumptions on the original data distribution, just that there exists a probability *p* of obtaining class A.